# In Clojure, how can I call a method on an object without using special dot notations?

Tags: clojure, macros

In Clojure I always use the . notation ie.

```
(.methCall obj args)
```

But is there a way to call the method without having that dot notation? Eg. the equivalent of something like "apply" when I turn

```
(f x y)
```

into

```
(apply f x y)
```

?

I wanna do this in order to write a macro that can take a method name as one of the arguments and call it on an object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the [dot special form](https://clojure.org/reference/java_interop#_the_dot_special_form)

E.g.

```
user=> (. (bigint 42) toString)
"42"
```

The form you are using is under [member access](https://clojure.org/reference/java_interop#_member_access) and is a shortcut:

```
user=> (macroexpand '(.toString (bigint 42)))
(. (bigint 42) toString)
```

Above docs state the following expansions:

> ```
> (.instanceMember instance args*) ==> (. instance instanceMember args*)
> (.instanceMember Classname args*) ==> (. (identity Classname) instanceMember args*)
> (.-instanceField instance) ==> (. instance -instanceField)
> (Classname/staticMethod args*) ==> (. Classname staticMethod args*)
> Classname/staticField ==> (. Classname staticField)
> ```